# Android AlarmManager Repeating stop after app killed by user

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have and Android receiver declared in the manifest

```
<receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.giorgos.END_REQUEST"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I set the repeating alarm in the main activity as follows

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.giorgos.PING_END_REQUEST");
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5000, 1000 * 20 , alarmIntent);
```

So far so good, but when the user force stops the application the alarm repetition is canceled and no more intent are delivered to the received.

How to overcome this and keep sending intent at a fixed rate of time to my receiver?
Maybe I should use a service or there is a better more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

When the user presses *force stop* the app goes into **STOPPED** state.Once the application is in stopped state,you can receive any events from the system.From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html)-

> Launch controls on stopped applications
>
> Starting from Android 3.1, the system's package manager keeps track of
> applications that are in a stopped state and provides a means of
> controlling their launch from background processes and other
> applications.
>
> Note that an application's stopped state is not the same as an
> Activity's stopped state. The system manages those two stopped states
> separately.
>
> The platform defines two new intent flags that let a sender specify
> whether the Intent should be allowed to activate components in stopped
> application.
>
> FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES — Include intent filters of stopped
> applications in the list of potential targets to resolve against.
> FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES — Exclude intent filters of stopped
> applications from the list of potential targets. When neither or both
> of these flags is defined in an intent, the default behavior is to
> include filters of stopped applications in the list of potential
> targets.
>
> Note that the system adds FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to all
> broadcast intents. It does this to prevent broadcasts from background
> services from inadvertently or unnecessarily launching components of
> stoppped applications. A background service or application can
> override this behavior by adding the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES
> flag to broadcast intents that should be allowed to activate stopped
> applications.
>
> Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but
> are not yet launched and when they are manually stopped by the user
> (in Manage Applications).

You can't do anything until the user launches the app again.

Comment: So is it possible to automatically launch the app from the background after user force-kills the app?